# Не работает условие или я написал что-то не так?

Tags: python, python-3.x, условия

При вводе -10 -10 -10, почему то выводит: -10 + -10 + -10 = -30, хотя не должно. Где я ошибся?

'''

```
a = float(input())
b = float(input())
c = float(input())

if a < 0:
    sl = a + b + c
    print(format(a, '.0f'), '+', format(b, '.0f'), '+', format(c, '.0f'), '=', format(sl, '.0f'))

elif b < 0:
    sl = a - b + c
    print(format(a, '.0f'), format(b, '.0f'), '+', format(c, '.0f'), '=', format(sl, '.0f'))

elif c < 0:
    sl = a + b - c
    print(format(a, '.0f'), '+', format(b, '.0f'), format(c, '.0f'), '=', format(sl, '.0f'))

elif a < 0 and b < 0:
    sl = a - b + c
    print(format(a, '.0f'), format(b, '.0f'), '+', format(c, '.0f'), '=', format(sl, '.0f'))

elif b < 0 and c < 0:
    sl = a - b - c
    print(format(a, '.0f'), format(b, '.0f'), format(c, '.0f'), '=', format(sl, '.0f'))

elif a < 0 and b < 0 and c < 0:
    sl = a - b - c
    print(format(a, '.0f'), ' ', format(b, '.0f'), ' ', format(c, '.0f'), '=', format(sl, '.0f'))

else:
    sl = a + b + c
    print(format(a, '.0f'), '+', format(b, '.0f'), '+', format(c, '.0f'), '=', format(sl, '.0f'))
```

'''

Comment: Интерпретатор при -10+-10+-10 тоже выводит -30. А какой результат должен быть?

Comment: Кстати срабатывает первое условие если что.

Comment: Если ввод -10 -10 -10, то результат должен быть: -10 -10 -10 = -30, но почему то так не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ответ на ваш вопрос - где ошиблись. Основная ошибка - вы не проверяете в большинстве условий знак каждого числа. К примеру, первое условие: в нем вы проверяете только знак `a`, а к остальным числам независимо от их реального знака приписываете `+`.
2. Если покороче переписать ваш код с использованием тернарного `if` и `abs()`, можно сделать так:

```
a, b, c = [float(f) for f in input("Введите 3 числа через пробел: ").split()]
out = f'{"-" if a < 0 else ""}{abs(a):.0f}{"-" if b < 0 else "+"}{abs(b):.0f}{"-" if c < 0 else "+"}{abs(c):.0f}={a + b + c:.0f}'
print(out)
```

```
Введите 3 числа через пробел: 10 -30 -5
10-30-5=-25
```

3. Вообще задача имеет циклический вид, поэтому удобнее сделать в цикле для произвольного кол-ва чисел:

```
numbers = [float(f) for f in input("Введите N чисел через пробел: ").split()]
out = ''
for n in numbers:
    out += f'{"-" if n < 0 else ("" if out == "" else "+")}{abs(n):.2f}'

out += f'={sum(numbers):.2f}'
print(out)
```

```
Введите N чисел через пробел: 24.2 -16.5 22 45 -2.2 42
24.20-16.50+22.00+45.00-2.20+42.00=114.50
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.